# redirect onclick event in react using react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I want to go to other pages in my react project using a `router-react-dom`. I created a function like this:

```
const {id} = props;
  const redirect = () => {
    console.log("redirecting...");
    const url = `/${id}`;
    return <Redirect to={url} />;
  };
```

Then I make props to other component like this:

```
      <BtnDetalii
        clickFn={redirect}
        text="apasa aici pentru mai multe detalii"
      />
```

and this is my btnDetalii component

```
const BtnDetalii = props => (
  <div onClick={() => props.clickFn()} className="detalii">
    {props.text}
  </div>
);
```

When I click the buton doesn't work. What I missed?

Comment: Which version of react-router are you using?

Comment: @Cosmin Ciolacu can you share your complete code in sandbox? or i posted solution check that i hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use React Router v4. Wrap your component with `withRouter` from `react-router-dom` and this way you can access `history` prop. After that you can `push` new url to your `history` prop.

I am not sure what is your code in the parent component where your `redirect` function is, but this is a simple example using `withRouter`. If you share more of your component I can change the snippet and add your code.

```
import React from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import BtnDetalii from "./BtnDetalii";

const Card = withRouter(({ history, ...props }) => {
    const redirect = () => {
        console.log("redirecting...");
        const id = props.id;
        const url = `detalii/${id}`;
        history.push(url);
    };
    return (
        <div className="today">
        <div className="data">{props.nume}</div>
        <img src={props.poza} className="img-icon" alt="poza" />
        <p className="text">{props.strada}</p>
        <BtnDetalii
            clickFn={redirect}
            text="apasa aici pentru mai multe detalii"
        />
        </div>
    );
});

export default Card;
```

Comment: ok but I work with a functional components not with class-based components

Comment: I will change it to function based component, can you add your component code ?

Answer (score 0):

Check this example for functional component and you can go through documentation for better understanding.

[React router dom for functional component](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/usehistory)

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

function HomeButton() {
  let history = useHistory();

  function handleClick() {
    history.push("/home");
  }

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
      Go home
    </button>
  );
}
```

Comment: for me it shows `TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`

Comment: Did you add history: MemoryHistory; to your props?

Comment: @CosminCiolacu are you using class based or function based component?

Comment: I use function-based component

Comment: @CosminCiolacu then it won't work. why don't you wrap your button in Link. it's another way to redirect